# Map between surfaces involving the hyperboloid

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $X$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$, with the poles at $(0, 0, 1)$ and $(0, 0, -1)$ removed.

Let $H$ be the surface in $\mathbb R^3$ defined by the equation $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$.

We define a function $F: X \to H$ as follows. For each $p \in X$, there exists a unique line $l$ through $p$ that intersects the $z$-axis at right angles. This line $l$ intersects $H$ at two points. We define $f(p)$ to be the point of intersection between $l$ and $H$ such that $p$ lies between the $z$-axis and $f(p)$.

I have tried to express that mathematically but I haven't been able to. I want to conclude the solution which is $$F(x,y,z)=\left(x\sqrt\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2},y\sqrt\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2},z\right).$$ Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to make the setup easier to understand. Could you please check that this edit has preserved your intent?

Comment: Yes, it is what I was trying to express. Thank you for making it clearer.

Comment: Cool. So how much progress have you made? For example, can you visualise this construction? Can you write down a parametrised equation for the line that I called $l$?

Comment: I have thought of $p+\lambda e_3$ where $e_3=(0,0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of the construction. The space is three-dimensional, but I can only draw a two-dimensional cross-section. You should visualise $X$ and $H$ as the "surfaces of revolution" that you get by rotating everything I've drawn about the $z$-axis.

[image]

Now let's tackle the problem. Suppose that $p = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is some point on $X$. Then the line $l$ is given by
$$ l = \{ (0, 0, z_0) + t(x_0, y_0, 0) : t \in \mathbb R \} = \{ (tx_0, ty_0, z_0)  : t \in \mathbb R \}.$$
To spell this out, $(0, 0, z_0)$ is the point where the line $l$ intersects the $z$-axis. Meanwhile, $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ is a direction vector along the line $l$; in fact, $(x_0, y_0, 0)$ is the displacement vector from $(0, 0, z_0)$ to $p$.

The points where $l$ and $H$ intersect are points of the form $(tx_0, ty_0, z_0)$, where $t$ satisfies the condition
$$ (tx_0)^2 + (ty_0)^2 - z_0^2 = 1.$$
This condition on $t$ is equivalent to
$$ t= \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{x_0^2 + y_0^2}}.$$
Since $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ lies on the unit sphere, we have $x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2 = 1$, so our condition on $t$ is equivalent to
$$ t = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}.$$

Thus $l$ intersects $H$ at the two points
$$ \left(x_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, y_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, z_0  \right), \qquad \left(-x_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, -y_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, z_0  \right).$$

The point $\left(x_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, y_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, z_0  \right)$ lies on the same side of the $z$-axis as $p$, whereas the point $\left(-x_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, -y_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, z_0  \right)$ lies on the opposite side of the $z$-axis from $p$. So
$$ F(p) = \left(x_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, y_0\sqrt{\frac{1 + z_0^2}{1 - z_0^2}}, z_0  \right).$$